# JSON.NET SelectToken with JSONPath

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to use JSON.NET SelectToken with JSONPath to select for example the value of longname (`eee`) where types is only `ggg`.

JSON snippet:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "components" : [
        {
           "longname" : "aaa",
           "shortname" : "bbb",
           "types" : [ "ccc", "ddd" ]
        },
        {
           "longname" : "eee",
           "shortname" : "fff",
           "types" : [ "ggg" ]
        }
     ]
  }]
```

I am unable to get the JSONPath syntax correct. I have tried the following which I think is close to the right solution but always returns `null`:

```
 o.SelectToken("results[0].components[?(@.types=='[ggg]')].longname")
```

I have referenced [Querying JSON with SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) and [# JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) with no joy.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I learnt a bit about JSONPath and had a play around ([using this](http://jsonpath.com/)), and I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it definitely works:

```
results[0].components[?(@.types.length==1&&@.types[0]=="ggg")].longname
```

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find any other information to suggest there is a more simple solution to this.

Comment: thanks - it appears from [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1318) that `@.length` on arrays isn't supported.